# ShadowSocks client doen't work

Tags: 14.04, networking, server

I just installed Shadowsocks on my ubuntu server. I can connect to the server via Android or Windows.

But I can't connect to the Shadowsocks server via my Ubuntu Desktop!
I have installed ShadowSocks client as the below link said.
https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-qt5/wiki/Installation

I get this error:

```
Initialising ciphers...
AES-256/CFB (aes-256-cfb) initialised.
Running in local mode.
TCP server listen failed.
```

what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

Try install `Python-pip` first by Opening up a terminal windows. Then entering the followings command `sudo apt-get install python-pip` Then, install
shadowsocks by again entering this command`sudo apt-get install shadowsocks`